# How to create input type file which is not showing if JS is disabled?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I have upload system which works fine with JS, but I want to create some way how to handle it if JS is disabled. Then I want to show default `<input type="file">`. Normally I replace it by button "Add photos".

Is it possible?

My code is here, but if I use JQuery to hide classis `<input type="file">` then it is showed some miliseconds and just then disapear. I need to disapper it before page is loaded.

HTML:

```
<button class="add-item__add-photo-btn">Add photos</button>
<input type="file" id="input-files" name="files[]" multiple accept="image/jpeg,image/jpg,image/gif,image/png">
```

JQuery:

```
$('#input-files').css({display: 'none'});
```

Thank you for advices.

Answer (score 1):

Use css to hide the input type file on load, and when page is loaded the run the document ready function to show the input type field.

CSS - make it hidden

```
#input-files{
 display:none 
}
#your-js-disabled-input{
 display:block;
}
```

JS -- if js is enabled, this code will run and show your input field and hide the non-js input field.

```
$(document).ready(()=>{ //page load
  $('#input-files').css({display: 'block'}); //show js supported input
  $('#your-js-disabled-input').hide(); //hide your non-js backup input
  //or
  $('#input-files').show(500);
  $('#your-js-disabled-input').hide();
})
```

Edit 2 - requirement change
CSS

```
#input-files{
 display:block;
}
```

JS

```
$(document).ready(()=>{ //page load
  $('#input-files').css({display: 'none'}); //show js supported input
})
```

Comment: There is misunderstanding. I need to have ```<input type="file">``` in code but it must be hidden if I use JS. But if JS is not enable I want to show it. Your code create the same situation as I have -  bcz JS is made input hidden after page is loaded - just I need to write more code.

Comment: just revert the css above to `display:block` and revert in js from `block` to `none`, I have edited the answer, let me know if that meets requirement.

Comment: The same problem, maybe I have some in my code, but if JS hide this input after page loading, it is still visible for a while on start of page loading.

Comment: you have to follow the flow of code, (1) first hide input type `<input type='file' style='display:none'>`  . (2) use css to show the file after page has loaded, for this css should be at the bottom of html body to apply a bit late , apply css `#input-element{ display:block}` . (3) now if js is enabled it will hide it automatically by using document ready function and .hide(), js can be placed at the bottom as well.  @Dump

Comment: Is css link at bottom of html good idea?

Comment: not the entire link you can just do at the end of body tag : `</body><style> #input-element{ display:block } </style>`

Comment: It is not working. It is still hidden.